# Else if to create a new variable DEBUG

Tags: r, debugging, if-statement

I want to create a new variable "influence" in my dataset (f) based on several conditions taking into account other variables. Here is my code:

```
f$influence <- if (f$ApportLysine_gj <=  f$LysBesoinPlus5 & f$ApportLysine_gj >= f$LysBesoinMoins5){  
f$influence = 1  
} else  if (f$ApportLysine_gj  > f$LysBesoinPlus5 & f$ApportLysine_gj < f$LysExces20){  
 f$influence = 2  
} else  if (f$ApportLysine_gj >= f$LysExces20) {  
f$influence = 3
} else  if (f$ApportLysine_gj < f$LysBesoinMoins5 & f$ApportLysine_gj > f$LysDeficit20){
f$influence = 4
} else {  
f$influence = 5}
```

I only get an error message "argument is of length zero".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `f$influence = 1` etc, try just `1`. (You are already starting the instruction with an assignment.) Also, maybe what you want is `?ifelse`.

Comment: I suggest adding some logical line breaks to the code (it’s conventional to at least break the line after an opening and before the closing brace) to make it more readable.

Comment: I tried to replace "f$influence = 1" with just "1" (and same for the other), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often find that if I have lots of `if`, `else if`, or `ifelse` in coding a variable, `dplyr`'s `case_when` is very handy. Please see below, keep in mind that I couldn't test this without having your data.

```
library(dplyr)

f %>%
  mutate(influence = case_when(
    ApportLysine_gj <= LysBesoinPlus5 & ApportLysine_gj >= LysBesoinMoins5 ~ 1,
    ApportLysine_gj  > LysBesoinPlus5 & ApportLysine_gj < LysExces20 ~ 2,
    ApportLysine_gj >= LysExces20 ~ 3,
    ApportLysine_gj < LysBesoinMoins5 & ApportLysine_gj > LysDeficit20 ~ 4,
    TRUE ~ 5
  ))
```

Comment: This is a good solution but if OP’s code doesn’t work then this won’t work either.

Comment: You make a good point. There could definitely be other issues, but without any data or feedback from OP, I can't be sure

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a logical index and assigning the values of the new variable according to its value.

```
f$influence <- 5
i <- f$ApportLysine_gj <= f$LysBesoinPlus5 & f$ApportLysine_gj >= f$LysBesoinMoins5
f$influence[i] <- 1
i <- f$ApportLysine_gj > f$LysBesoinPlus5 & f$ApportLysine_gj < f$LysExces20
f$influence[i] <- 2
i <- f$ApportLysine_gj >= f$LysExces20
f$influence[i] <- 3
i <- f$ApportLysine_gj < f$LysBesoinMoins5 & f$ApportLysine_gj > f$LysDeficit20
f$influence[i] <- 4
```